# default path for android devices

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I have a doubt with android devices.In my application i have given a path to store my db files and that path is

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("LocalDB10.db");
```

I want to know where this path available in android device or else is there some other path i have to specify.Any ideas??

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path should be available.  You might want to try to debug to see what the problem is.  As an added bonus, you can always try to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL` [permission in your air manifest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129d39606f2-8000).